# GestureDetector does not work

Tags: android, xamarin

I have the following implementation to detect user gesture, but it does not work.

```
public class CSViewController : Java.Lang.Object, GestureDetector.IOnGestureListener
{
   GestureDetector gestureDetector = null;
   View myView;
   public CSViewController (Context context, View myView) 
    {   
        this.context = context;
        this.myView = myView;
        //myView.Touch += async (object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e) => Console.WriteLine("touch");
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(myView.Context,this);
   }

   public bool OnScroll (MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("onscroll");
     return false;
   }
}
```

However, for testing purpose I wrote the following code, and it works.

```
myView.Touch += async (object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e) => Console.WriteLine("touch");
```

Where am I doing wrong when I am implementing `GestureDetector`?

Comment: are you implementing IOnGestureListener?

Comment: Hello Jason, do you have any clue where I am doing wrong or  what I am missing?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/gestures/create_a_gesture_listener/)?

Comment: Yes, based on that I wrote my code. I have other interface methods implemented but I am only testing `onScroll`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

I added the following code and it worked

```
myView.Touch += (object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e) => _gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e.Event);
```

Here is the solution:

```
public class CSViewController : Java.Lang.Object, GestureDetector.IOnGestureListener
{
   GestureDetector gestureDetector = null;
   View myView;
   public CSViewController (Context context, View myView) 
    {   
        this.context = context;
        this.myView = myView;
        myView.Touch += (object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e) => _gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e.Event);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(myView.Context,this);
   }

   public bool OnScroll (MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("onscroll");
     return false;
   }
}
```